# How to connect with bitcoin rpc through Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I'm having some trouble to connect to my local bitcoin node through Python. It seems the node refuses every call made through Python, but when using the bitcoin-cli everything works.

My Python script:

```
import simplejson as json
import requests

with open("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Bitcoin\\testnet3\\.cookie", "r") as creds:
    cookie = creds.read()

NODE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8332"
NODE_USER = cookie.split(":")[0]
NODE_PASSWORD = cookie.split(":")[1]

def rpc(method, params=[]):
    payload = json.dumps({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": "minebet",
        "method": method,
        "params": params
    })
    return requests.post(NODE_URL, auth=(NODE_USER, NODE_PASSWORD), data=payload).json()['result']

rpc('getnewaddress')
```

And the bitcoin.conf file:

```
testnet=1
server=1
gen=0
prune=1024
```

I'm always getting an:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I also tried using regular rpcuser and rpcpassword configuration in the bitcoin.conf file, as well as the newer rpcauth method, but they all didn't work.

Comment: try to use `pycoinnet`.

Comment: FYI there is a dedicated bitcoin Q&A site https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ on which you might be more likely to get a prompt response

Comment: did you restart bitcoind after defining your config? What about running it in daemon mode?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection Refused" most likely means there's simply nothing listening at the hostname and port to which you're attempting to connect. In your case, you're pulling credentials from the .cookie file in the "testnet" data directory but you're connecting to the default mainnet RPC port 8332. When you start bitcoind in "testnet" mode the default RPC port is 18332, not 8332.